# How to make server only functions in SignalR

Tags: c#, signalr

I want to use SignalR to push data to web clients.

```
public class PushHub : Hub
{
    public void Push(string data)
    {
        Clients.push(data);
    }
}

public class DataGenerator
{
    private readonly PushHub pushHub;

    public void DataGenerator(PushHub pushHub)
    {
        this.pushHub = pushHub;
    }

    public void Tick()
    {
        pushHub.Push("Ping");
    }
}
```

However, I don't want clients to be able to invoke this function.

From the server I just plan to invoke the function on the Hub object itself (unless that is a bad idea?).

But I don't want clients to be able to invoke push.

Does SignalR provide means for this (e.g. an attribute for server only functions)?

If I have to implement something myself, then I have some ideas, but I am not sure how good they are:

- Let another class access the Clients property, which will then call Push.
- Store some kind of Nonce in the HUB that only the server knows and pass that nonce as an extra parameter to Push.
- Check what the client id is from the context. I suppose it's not there when the function is called from a random thread.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand, why you create "Push" method as public if this is only used by the server? Make this method private and use it only when required in server-side code.

Comment: It is public because I want another class on the server to call it. I will update the question.

Comment: Do the clients need to have the `PushHub` available to them at all?  If not this may be a non-issue.  If `PushHub` isn't meant to be a client-side class, then simply preventing the clients access to it will solve all your problems.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Inheriting from Hub will expose its public methods to the clients.

My guess is that if you want to call clients from a server method without inheriting the class from Hub you can do so by resolving and getting hold of the hub object like this:

```
 public class Notifier
    {
        public static void Say(string message)
        {
            var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();
            context.Clients.say(message);
        }
    }
}
```

See the SignalR wiki on hubs: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Hubs

Comment: Thanks, I missed that bit. Looks like this is what I want. I guess it's a bit in the direction of my first alternative. I'll accept your answer when I get it to work.

Comment: Awesome, I'm digging SignalR so far ^^